# How to use powershell to merge specific tabs from a SharePoint document library that contains folders with list items that are Excel workbooks?

Tags: list, document-library, excel, document

I have a requirement to merge specific 'export' tabs (worksheets) that are contained within folders that are within a SharePoint document library.  The folders are 'top-level' items within list A.  Within each folder are subfolders which contain list items that are of type excel.  I would like to use powershell to iterate over list A and it's subfolders and grab the worksheet (tab) named 'export' merging them into a new excel workbook within List A (at the top level).

I can easily get the list of all folders/subfolders and list items (of type excel).  What I can't figure out is how to get an object instance (for lack of a better term) to each excel workbook (the list items).  To powershell, each item is just an item and not of type excel.  Can someone advise on how I might do this?  Thanks.

Comment: List? Or do you mean Library? What should the result be? An Excel file? If so, this can be done with Power Query in Excel.

Comment: My apologies. Yes it's a list.  Would someone provide a reference on how I might do this with Power Query?  I have a top-level document library that contains 18 folders.  Within each folder are an Archive folder and 3-4 excel workbooks representing monthly sales data.  I need to grab the 'export' worksheet from each of those workbooks within each of the 18 folders and combine them into a new workbook that I can then refresh as needed.  Much appreciated for any guidance you may be able to provide.